# Babel "exclude" is not excluding a directory

Tags: directory, next.js, babeljs

I am trying to instruct Babel to not transpile a specific directory (in the same way that it excludes node_modules).

I am using Next.js. When I run the build, it becomes extremely slow because babel is crawling through a massive js file until it gives this message:

```
The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /PATH/ as it exceeds
the max of 500KB.
```

in babel.config.json:

```
{
   ...,
   "exclude": ["node_modules", "prisma"]
}
```

Babel Version: 7.12.13